# Identify an old story about a group of humans engulfed by a slime-mold-like entity

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Comic story about a group of explorers/tourists on another planet who are engulfed by a large semi-sentient life form (eg a slime mold?). They are able to communicate, quarrel etc. but cannot escape (at least for a while).
Read this at least 40 years ago, any help appreciated...

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like Damon Knight's **"Four In One"** where they fall into the mold and are dissolved except for the brains and nerves.  Eventually they learn to control the thing, and make limbs and such.

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much.