# Short Sci-Fi story from the '60s, was there any follow up story?

Tags: story-identification

During the '60s and '70s there was a series of Sci-Fi short story collection anthologies. One story was particularly interesting and I am wondering if the story relates to any other, longer, ones.

This story started off by describing the oriental game of Go. This was being played out on a galactic scale. Just who was grabbing up planetary systems was not mentioned, but humans were involved.

A military expedition lands and explores a planet. One group falls into a gigantic "amoeba". It digests their useless body parts, except for their brains and additional bits and pieces that can help the thing survive.

Later, two of the expeditions' "brains" utilize the thing's abilities to eliminate the other (militaristic) brains, so that they can go and live in the wilderness. Was there any follow up story?

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/260769/short-story-about-explorers-landing-on-a-planet-being-absorbed-and-transformed (which is newer and has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 26):

The story is [“Four in One”](https://variety-sf.blogspot.com/2009/10/damon-knight-four-in-one-novelette-how.html) by Damon Knight, but to the best of my knowledge it was a standalone story with no follow-up of any kind. The link is to a review which suggest that you might like Eric Frank Russell if you liked that story, with which I agree.

The original publication is available online [here](https://archive.org/details/galaxymagazine-1953-02/page/n5/mode/2up).

Comment: Darn, you beat me to it. I knew the story, but had to look up the title.  Preview of the story here (some pages missing) https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rjOmBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT189&dq=%22spes%20hominis%20man's%20hope%22&pg=PT168#v=onepage&q=Four%20in%20one&f=false

Comment: Like Pete, I knew the story (and author) but had to look up the name.  This is, not surprisingly, a duplicate:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/29240/trying-to-identify-pre-1970s-short-story-involving-multiple-humans-absorbed-into/ https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71675/please-help-me-id-this-scifi-story-a-group-of-people-captured-and-absorbed-by/ https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49938/identify-an-old-story-about-a-group-of-humans-engulfed-by-a-slime-mold-like-enti/

Comment: @Buzz Not entirely a duplicate, though. They aren't asking about the title or author, but whether there was a continuation.

Comment: Also, this isn't asking about a gooey creature, this one is asking about galactic Go.

Comment: @McKay It makes no difference if the questions are about different aspects of the story — it’s still a duplicate if the answer is the same.

Comment: The question is asking for a yes or no answer.  Which this answer provides.